# How to delete a node from set?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gun

How can I delete a node from set?

For example, I want to delete `velociraptor` from `dinos` set. But when I run the script I still see two nodes behind `dinos` after `dinos.map().val(cb)` execution.

```
const Gun = require('gun');    
const gun = new Gun({ peers: [ 'https://localhost:8888/gun' ] });

const app = gun.get('park');
const dinos = app.get('dinos');

const velociraptor = app.get('velociraptor').put({
  statistics: {
    force: 9,
    speed: 15
  }
});

const trex = app.get('trex').put({
  statistics: {
    force: 25,
    speed: 5
  }
});

dinos.set(velociraptor);
dinos.set(trex);

//velociraptor.put(null);
app.get('velociraptor').put(null);

dinos.map().val((v, k) => {
  console.log(k);
  console.log(v);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can try this npm package which provides 'unset()' method for gun.

```
http://npmjs.com/package/gun-unset
```